# Centering slider in the window

Tags: css

Can't find solution for centering my slider. Here what I have http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/vbhDF
**cnt** have width 100% because I want that my **cnt-block** go beyond window. 
**cnt-wrap** has width 5200px for every cnt-blocks. 
How can i center my slider in center and my cnt-blocks go beyond window. Sorry for my awfull explanation. Thanks for advice

Comment: Can you explain more! what you mean by centring **slider**?

Comment: From your example, it doesn't look like you're animating between slides. You don't necessarily need to use a slider if there is no animation happening, you could instead just use a basic show/hide function to show the appropriate content when clicked.

Comment: Now I only want to prepeare html and css than go to js/jQuery.<br>Here what I want to achive http://ru.wix.com/website-template/view/html/748?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F3&bookName=create-master-c&galleryDocIndex=4

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your .ctn element to have a width of 100% to accomidate the child. You want to set it to the width that your slider should occupy (maybe 960px or 1120px or whatever) and center that. Probably need to set overflow hidden as well. Your .cnt-block-wrap width of 5200px will accommodate the slides inside.

```
 .cnt {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried that, it center the content but if I will be animate my block will be going beyond the cnt., but not the window

Comment: @YaroslavKuzyo Not sure I understand your comment, but I'm going to go and guess that the problem is you need a position on your container element. see the edit above.

Comment: Looking at your sample code above again, didn't notice before but it appears that you're horizontally scrolling the page using anchor tags to act as your slider? When you say 'center', I was thinking you meant to center a viewport for your slider, but are you actually saying that you want the content section that is scrolled to, to be centered on screen, and there would still be visible content to the left and to the right of it?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here what i'm goimg to do http://s1367.photobucket.com/user/Yaroslav_Kuzyo/media/animate-slider_zps4731168e.jpg.html <br> I'm going to animate by adding negative margin and if I use your solution my blocks goes beyond cnt and not window

Comment: I will be use anchor in JS now i want to center content like here http://ru.wix.com/website-template/view/html/748?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F3&bookName=create-master-c&galleryDocIndex=4

Comment: seems I found solution http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/ http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/vbhDF

Comment: @YaroslavKuzyo If you have found a solution, why don't you add it as an own answer?